# How Android UIAutomator 2 takeScreenshot on the App without WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

Say we have an app named `NoseBook`, this app doesn't has the permission of `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and we don't intent to request user for this permission.

`uiautomator2` is the selected blackbox test framework, and we're trying to capture a screenshot during the test and save it somewhere, which later can be pulled from AVD and saved as report.

The API called is [UiDevice#takescreenshot](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/uiautomator/UiDevice#takescreenshot) but the following error was shown

```
E/UiDevice: failed to save screen shot to file
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/test.png (Permission denied)
```

The error will go away if we add the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to the app `NoseBook` but it is not appropriate as this is only for our testing purpose, the actual app doesn't need that permission.

Note: screencap is the workaround i've noticed but I'm looking solution around `uiautomator` itself.

Environment: emulator API 25

Answer (score 0):

You can grant permission rule like this

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
abstract class UiAutomatorRunner {

    lateinit var context: Context

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    var grantPermissionRule: GrantPermissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    )
```